# Unable to find the origin of an Image | Angular App

Tags: angular, angular8

I am currently working on an Angular 8 app, the issue is for some reason there seems to be a request for an image in a specific page. And that too, it happens only if i serve from a build, and when i do just serve, there is no request for the image.

I did go through the relevant component, template, & css files, but i couldn't find anywhere the source of the request. Is there any way by which we can point it to the source Here are a few things i tried.

1. Inspect the image's initiator in the network tab, it points to all the script tag entries

```
    <script src="runtime.js"></script><script src="polyfills-es5.js" nomodule=""></script><script src="polyfills.js"></script><script src="scripts.js"></script><script src="vendor.js"></script><script src="main.js"></script>
```

2. Searched the file name in the editor and haven't found any references.
3. Tried searching through the HTML source code present in the elements tab(Chrome Browser).
4. Since there might be a chance that the reference might be dynamically generated, have split searched the file name and have gone through all the references like the name of the file is corporate_banner.png. Have split it to corporate and banner.

Any Suggestions pointing to solutions would be helpful.

Comment: I would comment evey single `html` files and try to see which one of them is requesting this image

Comment: You should also run a search in the `css` files to make sure it's not coming from any css property

Comment: @Plochie Sorry, if it was possible to share, i would have already shared the repository.

Comment: @nircraft Have tried that too. Have scanned the entire repository.

Comment: Does that happen on a specific screen or when the app loads? DO you have any services that provide the image urls/src that gets bind to any component like header/footer etc.?

Comment: Are you sure image is not getting generated from backend data?

Comment: @nircraft like mentioned above, it happens only in a specific page. that too only in case of build, while i just do serve, there is no request.

Comment: @JacopoSciampi I removed the entire html from that template and still there is a request.